# Images on SSL enabled site with Internet explorer

Tags: ssl, domain, internet-explorer-8, images

I have a problem with my site after implementation of SSL that images do not appear. The scenario is that images come from images.domain.com (hosted on Amazon S3) and my certificate is for www.domain.com.

This problem only seems to happen in IE and not in any other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are using that domain name then they don't get the SSL certificate because they're on Amazon S3. In order to serve them up via HTTPS/SSL you have to use the S3 domain name. Two possibilities:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<key> (use the S3 certificate)

<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key> (use the *.s3.amazonaws.com wildcard certificate)
```

Depending on your bucket name, you may have issues with some browsers with the latter (such as having periods in the name for the virtual hosting method) so you'll need to use the former.